# Connect <select> options to <figure>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, figure

Not entirely sure how much needed information I can provide since I'm a noob. Hope you brainpower people can figure something out with what I can provide. I found some free code, from I think CodePen, for an image slider. It uses some sort of "dots" to swap beautifully between pics.

```
<div class="x">
<figure data-color="#aaa, #bbb">
      <img src="1.png" />
    </figure>
<figure data-color="#ccc, #ddd">
      <img src="2.png" />
    </figure>
  </div>
```

I have a select thingy beneath it and I would like the slider to respond to the options in the dropdown menu. For example, if I select the option value "hello" the first figure would activate, and if I select "Bye" the second figure would activate.

```
<select>
 <option value="Select Things">Select Things</option>
 <option value="Hello">Hello</option>
 <option value="Bye">Bye</option>
</select>
```

Is there a simple way to do this? Maybe OnChange or something? Or Maybe if each figure had some sort of class or value that I can call from the select menu? Or maybe it's even doable with just html?

Would also be neat if it's doable in the opposite order; if I click the first figure the select-box goes to the "Hello" value etc.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't polished, but should be enough to get you started. I added some comments throughout the code, so please have a look at those. No external libraries were used.

```js
var figures = document.querySelectorAll('figure');

function selectListener() {
  var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
  // If the "Select things" option is selected, do nothing
  if (selectedIndex > 0) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= figures.length; i++) {
      if (i === this.selectedIndex) {
        figures[i-1].classList.add('active');
      } else {
        figures[i-1].classList.remove('active');
      }
    }  
  }
}

document
  .querySelector('select')
  .addEventListener('change', selectListener)
```

```css
figure {
  transition: 0.5s opacity;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1em 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

figure.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- Added selected attribute to active option -->
<select>
  <option value="Select Things">Select Things</option>
  <option selected value="Hello">Hello</option>
  <option value="Bye">Bye</option>
</select>

<div class="x">
  <!-- Note: active class manually added to first figure -->
  <figure class="active" data-color="#aaa, #bbb">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
  </figure>
  <figure data-color="#ccc, #ddd">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris" />
  </figure>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/njzhwcg7/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I will try to tinker around with your code to see how well it fits into my environment. Will check back in a few moments. Much appreciated!

Comment: No clue why, but this didn't work for me. It doesn't make any option/figure selected and changing between them makes no difference. I can clearly see it works just fine in your fiddle, so I guess it's colliding with some other code on my end? Tried adding an alert to the javascript that I put in a .js-file to see if it actually read anything from the file, got the alert. Clues?

Comment: Got the select option to heed to "selected", but figure still don't respond.

Comment: What do you see in your developer tools console? Any errors?

Comment: As an aside (if you're wondering), people are downvoting your question because you didn't really show how you tried to resolve the issue yourself.

Comment: I get this error in console: TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

Comment: Yeah, I should probably have stated what I've done before posting. My bad. I tried some OnChange variants but couldn't figure out how to make it do what I want. Also did some 2 hours of googling which didn't make me brighter. And I'm not knowledgeable enough to come up with, and brute force, an own solution for this.

Comment: I managed to solve it with a new approach. The code from CodePen does all sort of weird stuff to the figures, classes of elements inside of them etc. It's not a pretty solution but it works.

document.getElementById("idX").addEventListener("click", swapDropX); 
function swapDropX() {
document.getElementById('selectID').value = 'Hi';
}

And to make it work backwards:

function swapPic() {
var e = document.getElementById("selectID");
var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; 

if (val === 'Hi') {
document.getElementById("idX").click();
} else if ...other val's.

Learned a lot.